# MacBook Pro wifi drivers

Tags: networking, 20.04, broadcom, macbook-pro, ubuntu-drivers

I have a MacBook Pro 2019 13 inch with two thunderbolt 3 ports. I'm currently running ubuntu 20.04 dual booted with Mac OS. I'm currently typing this from Mac OS.

The wifi is not connecting automatically and I do not know the type of drivers I need for that. I know the software update app itself is supposed to inform me about that, but it can't tell since there is no wifi.

Everything else (keyboard, Touch Bar) works normally after I followed some steps from other guides online. I have ran the command `sudo lshw -C network`. I apologise for being unable to paste the output here as I can't connect to wifi there so...

The output of the command `sudo lshw -C network`:
[image]

Here is the output of the command `lscpi -nnk |grep 0280 -A3`:
[image]

Here are the outputs of the commands `ping c3- 8.8.8.8`, `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com` and `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`:
[image]

Apparently, ping is missing on Ubuntu 20.04, focal fossa. I've googled it and apparently, it's quite a common issue or so according to the number of guides up there. I tried installing the ping package, but due to the problematic hotspot from my iPhone, it failed.

Here is the guide I referred to: https://linuxconfig.org/ping-command-not-found-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Here is the output of the commands

1. sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf

2)sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

3)sudo apt update

4)ping -c3 8.8.8.8

5)sudo apt install iputils-ping

6)sudo dmesg | grep brcm

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YTy6R3B7n6/
output of ip addr show: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YVDt5VgTkQ/

Comment: I'm willing to run any other commands that will be useful in troubleshooting.

Comment: You seem to have a working USB ethernet device. Can you connect it and temporarily get an internet connection? Please run the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` We only need the pci.id, something like: [14e4:4599]. If there are two shown, show both in the order that they appear. Please edit your question to show the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: The problem is that is my iPhone. While my iPhone claims that hotspot is connected, I couldn't visit any website in Firefox.

Comment: Please edit your question to show: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and also: `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com` and, finally: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 1):

This will be an incomplete answer as there are several seperate issues here. I will edit the answer as we uncover further details.

First, resolv.conf is incorrect. Please do:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

As the terminal suggests, please next run:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then try again:

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
```

If the command `ping` is still not found, then, try to install it:

```
sudo apt install iputils-ping
```

Your output suggests that the wireless device already has an appropriate driver, *brcmfmac*, but probably lacks firmware. We can find out with:

```
sudo dmesg | grep brcm
```

As the output may be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I did connect to hotspot on my phone, but as usual it failed.

Comment: Please run: `ip addr show` Does the interface enxacde48001122 have a valid IP (inet) address? It may be that you are connected to the hotspot but that the hotspot is not properly connected to the internet.

Comment: Is the issue unsolvable then?

Comment: "Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4377-pcie.bin failed with error -2" After several Google searches, I am unable to find the required firmware file to download and install. As of today, 07JUL2021, I regret that I haven't any other suggestions.

Comment: I've found a solution that worked on the 2018 mbp so I'm doing a last ditch effort right now before I ditch ubuntu get windows 11 or something since I'm getting sick of mac os. Here's the thing: install the deb file of the iwd package, and then modify networkmanager.conf lto say this:

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you!

First, make sure you can make an internet connection with a cable. A basic Bluetooth tethering should work.

Next, paste the following commands in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Enjoy!
If this works for you, mark it as the right answer!